# Use strings to access formal R class object elements

Tags: r, class, object, subquery

I am writing a function to access elements of a formal R class ([Dada2](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dada2/versions/1.0.3/topics/dada-class)). My elements require a unique identifier to access the class. I am currently parsing a string to get that identifier and then need to use that string to access the information in the data class. I would like to automate this script which is why I am parsing the unique identifier. I can easily access the data manually, however with the shear number of samples that is not ideal.

Variables: Dada_Object (Large list with multiple items)
           sample (Character string name)

Goal:

```
Unique_Identifier = Parsing_Function(sample)

Desired = Dada_Object[Unique_Identifier]$sequences
```

Problem: Using the unique identifier does not allow access to the sequences information. The unique identifier is currently a string object. Any direction to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with an adhoc method.

I began by subsetting the class list then unlisting the elements

```
Step_1 = Dada_Object[Unique_Identifier]
Step_2 = unlist(Step_1)
```

From here I was able to subset the named list elements

```
Desired_Output = names(Step_2)[1:Desired_Output_Length]
```

This solution was a workaround, however I am still curious if anyone has a better way to access class items using strings.